# Android Google Map CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android app that records on a Google Map the path a user follows while traveling. As the user moves, I collect the location data into an sqlite database and update a LatLngBounds and an ArrayList holding all the locations making up the path. The camera view for the map can be set to be centered so as to encompass the entire path, centered on the beginning of the path, or centered on the end of the path. When the camera view changes from one setting to another, I'd like to animate the camera. That's where I'm having a problem.

When I switch to take in the whole path, camera animation works as I intend with the following line of code:

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mLatLngBounds, 110);
```

However, trying to zoom to the starting point or the ending`point doesn't work. When I switch to centering over the starting or ending  point (latLng), I want the camera to zoom to the zoom level that was used when the camera was last centered there, but with a minimum zoom level of 17.0f. Here are the different ways I've tried:

```
float zoom = 17.0f;
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

float zoom = 17.0f;
CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

float zoom = 17.0f;
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
```

None of these approaches worked. In every instance the camera centered on the designated LatLng, but the zoom level on the map remained where it was immediately before trying to animate the camera. For what it's worth, substituting moveCamera() for animateCamera() worked as I expected in all the variants listed above, with the camera centered over the designated LatLng and (if the prior zoom level was < 17.0f) zoomed to 17.0f. Does anyone have suggestions for what else to try to make the zoom feature work with animateCamera()? Thanks!

Comment: CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.getCenter(), 17f);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(cu);

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to zoom in over the starting or ending point of the route, but have consistently found that simply inserting either of those LatLngs into newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom) does not work; the camera moves to the proper point, but there's no zoom. I do find, however, that if I put in a moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.getCenter(), zoom) immediately before my call to animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom) I  get something like the effect I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @knutsondc I'm also having this exact issue. Did you find a resolution for it?

Comment: And also zoom value in here is not same as map.position.zoom. So i can not get map zoomed value and update it here. There are different.